# Filtrar array de objetos por outro array de objetos retornando os diferentes

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Possuo dois arrays de objetos um de usuarios e outro de usuarioEstrututural e preciso filtrar o de usuarios pelo usuarios Estrutural, tentei algumas abordagem mas sem sucesso. Abaixo segue o código:

```js
let usuarios = [
    {
        "id": "f8a4aa6e-5168-44a5-aa99-94c78e69b8bd",
        "nome": "Nadson"        
    },
    {
        "id": "bd15520d-75cb-438e-b9de-fd623d4b30e3",
        "nome": "Paulo Vinicius"        
    },  
    {
        "id": "f003e8e0-c2c9-49cb-9dc2-4a5fd773cc12",
        "nome": "Marcos Vinicius"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "5f4ce9c7-495a-4b97-9568-af7cebc3669d",
        "nome": "Milena"
        
    },
    {
        "id": "223fac6a-be4b-46a4-94a5-dfd608a1bb20",
        "nome": "Claudio"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "704c1bfb-5493-4adc-bc32-60e2f9f0cd5e",
        "nome": "Ana Maria"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "397a0763-9a6c-4064-8dfb-d7e8834bf104",
        "nome": "Roberto "
    
    },
    {
        "id": "9186cbc8-227b-4018-80fc-46fd37e4a3e2",
        "nome": "JoÃ£o"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "da592e59-d250-4edc-b777-2c9d8b2aa175",
        "nome": "Maria"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "df174d37-78e6-41aa-a5f6-b687d63f0a88",
        "nome": "Marcos"
        
    },
    {
        "id": "4d009231-0eea-4414-83fd-a9915b5e396c",
        "nome": "Antonio"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "d1f6518d-4b68-46c1-9872-ac82fbb52148",
        "nome": "Pedro"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "b04a9840-13df-4c45-827e-bd0bc72b6c7f",
        "nome": "Silvio"
    
    }
];


const usuariosEstrutural = [
  {
    "nmUsuario": "Ana Maria Ferreira da Silva",
    "id": 21,    
    "value": "9c6e250b-774c-4f0a-9c3f-ef218d96aca4",
    "cdEmpresa": "319bd570-96ac-4d67-99f9-9085faed83f9",
    "cdUsuario": "704c1bfb-5493-4adc-bc32-60e2f9f0cd5e"
    
  },
  
  {
    "nmUsuario": "Nadson Oliveira",
    "id": 22,    
    "value": "9c6e250b-774c-4f0a-9c3f-ef218d96aca4",
    "cdEmpresa": "319bd570-96ac-4d67-99f9-9085faed83f9",
    "cdUsuario": "f8a4aa6e-5168-44a5-aa99-94c78e69b8bd",
   
  },
  {
    "nmUsuario": "Milena dos Santos Silva",
    "id": 29,   
    "cdEmpresa": "319bd570-96ac-4d67-99f9-9085faed83f9",
    "cdUsuario": "5f4ce9c7-495a-4b97-9568-af7cebc3669d",
    "idUsuarioCadastro": "f8a4aa6e-5168-44a5-aa99-94c78e69b8bd",
   
  },
  {
    "nmUsuario": "Paulo Vinicius Ferreira lima",
    "id": 31,    
    "cdEmpresa": "319bd570-96ac-4d67-99f9-9085faed83f9",
    "cdUsuario": "bd15520d-75cb-438e-b9de-fd623d4b30e3",
   
  },
  
];

//primeira tentativa

const index = 0; 

for (const estrutura of usuariosEstrutural ) {
    for (const usu of usuarios) {
        index++;
        if (usu.id === estrutura.cdUsuario) {             
            usuarios.splice(0, index);
        }
    }
}

//segunda tentativa

const usuariosFiltrados = usuarios.filter(usu => usuariosEstrutural.filter(estrutu => estrutu.cdUsuario !== usu.id).legth )
```

Tentei essas duas abordagens, mas o resultado não vem filtrado como deveria, o mesmo deverá exibir somente os usuarios que não estão contidos no array de usuariosEstrutural.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `find` para verificar se um objeto existe em um array, a sua segunda tentativa estava quase certa, fica assim:

```
const usuariosFiltrados = usuarios.filter(usu => {
    const encontrou = usuariosEstrutural.find(estrutu => estrutu.cdUsuario === usu.id);

    // "!" para negar, ou seja, filtrar apenas os que não foram encontrados
    return !encontrou; 
});
```

Segue abaixo seu exemplo corrigido

```js
let usuarios = [
    {
        "id": "f8a4aa6e-5168-44a5-aa99-94c78e69b8bd",
        "nome": "Nadson"        
    },
    {
        "id": "bd15520d-75cb-438e-b9de-fd623d4b30e3",
        "nome": "Paulo Vinicius"        
    },  
    {
        "id": "f003e8e0-c2c9-49cb-9dc2-4a5fd773cc12",
        "nome": "Marcos Vinicius"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "5f4ce9c7-495a-4b97-9568-af7cebc3669d",
        "nome": "Milena"
        
    },
    {
        "id": "223fac6a-be4b-46a4-94a5-dfd608a1bb20",
        "nome": "Claudio"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "704c1bfb-5493-4adc-bc32-60e2f9f0cd5e",
        "nome": "Ana Maria"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "397a0763-9a6c-4064-8dfb-d7e8834bf104",
        "nome": "Roberto "
    
    },
    {
        "id": "9186cbc8-227b-4018-80fc-46fd37e4a3e2",
        "nome": "JoÃ£o"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "da592e59-d250-4edc-b777-2c9d8b2aa175",
        "nome": "Maria"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "df174d37-78e6-41aa-a5f6-b687d63f0a88",
        "nome": "Marcos"
        
    },
    {
        "id": "4d009231-0eea-4414-83fd-a9915b5e396c",
        "nome": "Antonio"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "d1f6518d-4b68-46c1-9872-ac82fbb52148",
        "nome": "Pedro"
    
    },
    {
        "id": "b04a9840-13df-4c45-827e-bd0bc72b6c7f",
        "nome": "Silvio"
    
    }
];


const usuariosEstrutural = [
  {
    "nmUsuario": "Ana Maria Ferreira da Silva",
    "id": 21,    
    "value": "9c6e250b-774c-4f0a-9c3f-ef218d96aca4",
    "cdEmpresa": "319bd570-96ac-4d67-99f9-9085faed83f9",
    "cdUsuario": "704c1bfb-5493-4adc-bc32-60e2f9f0cd5e"
    
  },
  
  {
    "nmUsuario": "Nadson Oliveira",
    "id": 22,    
    "value": "9c6e250b-774c-4f0a-9c3f-ef218d96aca4",
    "cdEmpresa": "319bd570-96ac-4d67-99f9-9085faed83f9",
    "cdUsuario": "f8a4aa6e-5168-44a5-aa99-94c78e69b8bd",
   
  },
  {
    "nmUsuario": "Milena dos Santos Silva",
    "id": 29,   
    "cdEmpresa": "319bd570-96ac-4d67-99f9-9085faed83f9",
    "cdUsuario": "5f4ce9c7-495a-4b97-9568-af7cebc3669d",
    "idUsuarioCadastro": "f8a4aa6e-5168-44a5-aa99-94c78e69b8bd",
   
  },
  {
    "nmUsuario": "Paulo Vinicius Ferreira lima",
    "id": 31,    
    "cdEmpresa": "319bd570-96ac-4d67-99f9-9085faed83f9",
    "cdUsuario": "bd15520d-75cb-438e-b9de-fd623d4b30e3",
   
  },
  
];


//segunda tentativa

const usuariosFiltrados = usuarios.filter(usu => !usuariosEstrutural.find(estrutu => estrutu.cdUsuario === usu.id) )

console.log(usuariosFiltrados);
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, ajudou muito!! Deu super certo sua tratativa!!